# Python: split row with multiple delimiters and return in specific format

Tags: python, split, format

I have a txt file with the following tuple format

```
    ABC-01 name1,10
    DEF-02 name2,11
    GHI-03 name3,12
    JKH-04 name4,13
```

**I may not be able to use import re. Need to do without re.**

I need to split the tuples at the delimiters(ABC-01 and others are one word and I need to keep the hyphen). My output needs to be as follows

**Format of the needed result**

```
        Out[]: 
           [(u'name1', u'ABC-01 10'),
            (u'name2', u'DEF-02 11'), 
            (u'name3', u'GHI-03 12 '),
            (u'name4', u'JKL-04 13')]
```

Here's what I have tried till now and the output I get

**Solution 1:**

```
              def split_func(line):
              line_mod = line.split(' ')
              line_mod1 = line_mod.split(',')
              print line_mod1
```

**Result**

```
      Attribute Error : list object has no attribute split
```

**Solution 2:**

```
          def split_func(line):
                line_mod = line.split(' ')
                a,b,c = str(line_mod).split(',')
                return (b,a + " " + c)
```

**Result**

```
             [(" u'name1", "[u'ABC-01' 10]"),
              (" u'name2", "[u'DEF-02' 11]"),
              (" u'name3", "[u'GHI-03' 12]"),
              (" u'name4", "[u'JKL-04' 13]")]
```

How can I get the exact format that I am trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `re` example below.

```
import re


def main():
    result = []
    with open("test.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            result.append(split_func(line.strip()))
    print(result)


def split_func(line):
    a, b, c = re.split("\s|,+", line)
    return b, a + " " + c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**OR**

Here is one without `re`

```
def main():
    result = []
    with open("test.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            result.append(split_func(line.strip()))
    print(result)


def split_func(line):
    a, b = line.split(' ')
    b, c = b.split(',')
    return b, a + " " + c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With the output looking like this

```
[('name1', 'ABC-01 10'), ('name2', 'DEF-02 11'), ('name3', 'GHI-03 12'), ('name4', 'JKH-04 13')]
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidJones. The 2nd function without re works as expected

Comment: No problem, glad i helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
def split_func(line):
    a, b = line.split(' ')
    c, d = b.split(',')
    return c, ' '.join([a, d])
```

Your **Solution 1** does not work because `split()` returns a list and you can't use `split()` on a list.

For **Solution2**

```
x = ['ab', 'cd']
```

`str(x)` gives `"['ab', 'cd']"`

What you need is `join()` function.